# Naming and overloading

Tags: c#, .net

I have two method overloads:

```
bool HasRight(RightType rightType, string cityId);
bool HasRight(RightType rightType, string cityAlias);
```

Of course it won't compile as methods signatues are the same. What is the best way to solve naming problem in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would you immediately be able to distinguish between an id and an alias? How about simply:

```
bool HasRight(RightType rightType, string cityIdOrAlias)
```

If it isn't clear cut, something like "if it starts with `:`, for example `:nyc`, then it is an id, else it is assumed to be an alias". Other options:

- suffixed names:

  ```
  bool HasRightById(RightType rightType, string cityId)
  bool HasRightByAlias(RightType rightType, string cityAlias)
  ```
- take both and demand exactly one inside the method:

  ```
  bool HasRight(RightType rightType, string cityId, string cityAlias)
  ```

Answer (score 6):

Use different method names, **don't misuse overloading for semantically-disconnected things**.

For example:

```
bool HasRightById(RightType rightType, string cityId);
bool HasRightByAlias(RightType rightType, string cityAlias);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your only option is to rename one or both functions when you can't change the datatype of one of its parameters:

HasRightById / HasRightByAlias

Answer (score 2):

You can use an enum for that like this...

```
public bool HasRight(RightType rightType, string value, RightValue valueType)
{
    if (valueType == RightValue.CityAlias)
    {

    }
    else if (valueType == RightValue.CityId)
    {

    }
}

public  enum RightValue
{
    CityId, CityAlias 
}
```

or different names for the method

```
bool HasRightByCityAlias(RightType rightType, string cityAlias)
{
}

bool HasRightByCityId(RightType rightType, string cityId)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Better set names of methods, that means something:

```
bool HasRightById(RightType rightType, string cityId);
bool HasRightByAlias(RightType rightType, string cityAlias);
```

Answer (score 0):

since the runtime is looking at method name and parameter types (not parameter names) to resolve the method calls, you either change the name or you change a parameter type. in general I have one method having a suffis, something like:

```
bool HasRightId(RightType rightType, string cityId);
bool HasRightAlias(RightType rightType, string cityAlias);
```

you like it or not, there is nothing else to do than changing the name, if you cannot pass `Id` as `int`...

Answer (score 0):

You have to name the two methods differently, with meaningful names:

```
bool HasRightById(RightType rightType, string cityId); 
bool HasRightByAlias(RightType rightType, string cityAlias);
```

Alternatively, if you target .NET 4.0 or later, you could use named arguments with default values:

```
bool HasRight(RightType rightType, string cityId = null, string cityAlias = null);
```

You then have to ensure that one of cityId and cityAlias is not null, and execute the corresponding code.